# asp.net c# convert filestream to image

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream

i have a filestream which im trying to convert into a image. i have the following code

```
FileStream imageFile = image["file"] as FileStream;
```

image is a map holding information on the image. please can some one direct me on what I should do next.

Comment: Why are you duplicating the `image` variable name? I doubt what you have will compile.

Comment: What do you mean 'convert to an image' - do you mean turn it into a `Bitmap` instance or serve it up to a client in response to an image request?

Comment: the image is on a server and I get it using a FileStream, the idea is to display the image on a web page.

Answer (score 6):

`Image.FromStream` will take a stream and return an image. Incidentally, if you use `Bitmap.FromStream` or `Image.FromStream`, or indeed any of these methods, they all return a `Bitmap`, so they can all be upcast to `Bitmap` from `Image` if you want them to be.

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
        int width = 128;
        int height = width;
        int stride = width / 8;
        byte[] pixels = new byte[height * stride];

        // Define the image palette
        BitmapPalette myPalette = BitmapPalettes.Halftone256;

        // Creates a new empty image with the pre-defined palette
        BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
            width,
            height,
            96,
            96,
            PixelFormats.Indexed1,
            myPalette,
            pixels,
            stride);

        FileStream stream = new FileStream("new.jpg", FileMode.Create);
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.FlipHorizontal = true;
        encoder.FlipVertical = false;
        encoder.QualityLevel = 30;
        encoder.Rotation = Rotation.Rotate90;
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
        encoder.Save(stream);
```